# Cross Browser dropdown/popup menu over a flash movie

Tags: javascript, css, flash, xhtml, drop-down-menu

I need to make my dropdown menu apprear over the top of a flash movie, how is this done cross browser?

It can be done, IBM do it: http://www.ibm.com/us/ so do GE: http://www.ge.com/

Setting the the WMODE to transparent doesn't work for Firefox

Putting it into an Iframe doesnt work below IE7

Any one know the best way to achieve this?

Comment: GE doesn't work for me. FF 3.0.5 on Linux.  
I see Flash and I see DHTML on IBM, but not together.
I've used the iframe shim method successfully before.

Answer (score 3):

Set the wmode to transparent and if necessary, use z-index as you would on any other element, that really should work for Firefox too.

Answer (score 3):

here is an example with all three modes: opaque, transparent and no wmode at all

http://www.communitymx.com/content/source/E5141/wmodeopaque.htm

use transparent if you have something under the flash movie that you want visible,
opaque if you don't want to show what's underneath

and set a higher z-index for menu than the flash movie has

Answer (score 1):

Firefox for linux shows flash on top of everything. Regardles of wmode or z-index.

EDIT:
I just found out that the Linux issue described above can be "fixed".

You need to add an iframe with a z-index between the swf and the layer you want to put on top of it. The iframe needs to have style="display:none" initially and you must use javascript to set display:block on it after the flash plugin has initialized. The Iframe will hide all swfs that are below it on linux.